# Any idea to play .3gp video in html5 player (or custom library)

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, 3gp

Maybe somebody has a good idea to play `.3gp` video in modern browsers? Maybe using any custom library (searched them - nothing good was found), not default `html5` `video` player?

Just checked `caniuse`, and seems that's not supported yet.
https://caniuse.com/#search=3gp

I have read a lot of questions & answers, and most of them I think - are outdated.

Are there any updates, with playing custom video-formats in modern browsers?

Comment: go to http://www.zamzar.com/ and convert it

Comment: @mlegg not a good idea...